# bash substring of command instead of variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, substring

I can do this in bash:

```
foo=bar
echo ${foo:0:2}
```

which prints 'ba' (the first two characters of 'bar').

Now I want to do the same with a script/command output instead of a variable, like so:

```
echo ${$(date):0:10}
```

But then I get an error: "bad substitution".

Of course I can use an intermediary variable:

```
foo=$(date)
echo ${foo:0:10}
```

But is there a way to do this directly?

P.S. The `date` command is just an example, this is not about generating some date string in a particular format. Just the general concept of taking a substring from an arbitrary shell command output.

Comment: No BASH syntax doesn't allow any kind of nesting.

Comment: To be clear, `date` is just an example command here, not the point of the question?

Comment: @chepner Yes, `date` was just a random command for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, BASH syntax doesn't allow any kind of nesting. You can do so using external utilities like `cut`:

```
date | cut -c 1-10
```

```
Wed Jun 13
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace `date`:

```
$ date
Wed Jun 13 14:57:38 EEST 2018
```

you can use `printf`:

```
$ printf "%(%a %b %d%n)T"
Wed Jun 13
```

`man strftime` for more format modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output `Wed Jun 13` for today's date (which this is), then

```
$ date +'%a %b %e'
Wed Jun 13
```

See the manual for `date` and/or for `strftime` on your system.